# TSV output not supported. Tesseract >=3.05 required in AWS Linux server

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, tesseract, yum, python-tesseract

tesseract 3.04.00 available in AWS Linux server.
when I try to use pytesseract.image_to_data() function It Gives run time error like
"TSV output not supported. Tesseract >= 3.05 required"

so how can I resolve this issue?

hint*
I installed tesseract using belove mention codes

```
https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
yum -y update
yum -y install tesseract
```

AWS server info

```
NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use other Linux distribution that has no problem with support of a recent version of packages (e.g. tesseract 5) Tesseract 3.04.00 was released on [24 Jul 2015](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/releases?page=2)